# Ansible import role run conditionally

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am writing a parent ansible role that runs another role though import_role. The idea that this sibling role (staticdev.pyenv) only runs when an argument `pyenv_python_versions` is passed, otherwise this is skipped.

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html), I tried the following approach:

parent/tasks/main.yml

```yaml
---
- name: Install pyenv
  import_role:
    name: staticdev.pyenv
  vars:
    pyenv_owner: "{{ ansible_env.USER }}"
    pyenv_path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/pyenv"
    pyenv_global: "{{ pyenv_global }}"
    pyenv_python_versions: "{{ pyenv_python_versions }}"
    pyenv_virtualenvs: []
  when: pyenv_python_versions
```

I am using currently ansible 4.1.0 (core 2.11.1), and when I test it on Debian 11 (image: cisagov/docker-debian11-ansible:latest) it executes the role anyway, even without any value for `pyenv_python_versions`. `when` is not being considered and I also tried with `include_role`. Complete logs can be found [here](https://github.com/staticdev/ansible-role-python-developer/runs/2806219973).

Any idea?

UPDATE: changed condition `when` from to pyenv_python_versions as suggested by @lonetwin.

Comment: Without testing this, my guess would be the reason the task is executed is because the variable `pyenv_python_versions` **is** being defined (the 4th line in `var` declaration), even if the /value/ of the `{{ pyenv_python_versions }}` is empty. I suspect it would work, if you change the conditional to `when: pyenv_python_versions` (ie: simply asset the value rather than the variable being defined).

Comment: Nice try @lonetwin, but unfortunatelly, still same result. I updated the description and execution logs with your suggestion.

Comment: => `when: pyenv_python_versions | default('') | length > 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was role import was replicating variables from the imported role (**pyenv_global, pyenv_python_versions** and **pyenv_virtualenvs**), in this case you solve it just by omitting imported role params (they will be overwritten if you create new defaults for them).

Solution:

```
---
- name: Install pyenv
  import_role:
    name: staticdev.pyenv
  vars:
    pyenv_owner: "{{ ansible_env.USER }}"
    pyenv_path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/pyenv"
  when: pyenv_python_versions
```